# Can I trust all packages in the Ubuntu official repository?

Tags: security, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ubuntu repositories are totally safe and free from malware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52858/which-ubuntu-repositories-are-totally-safe-and-free-from-malware)

Can I trust all packages in the Ubuntu official repository? What security verifications are done for these packages?